# XMLHttpRequest - Ajax request - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

**Question Background:**

I have a Basic MVC app with a single View which uses an AJAX request to call a simple WepApi appI have hosted in Azure. The WebApi is used to render a pdf document which is opened in the Success methof of the AJAX request.

**The Issue:**

When I call the WebApi url I am receiving the following error in Chrome's console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/PdfHandler/PdfButtonCaller.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'http://localhost:1570' is therefore not allowed access.
The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

**I have added the Chrome Allow Control Origin Control plugin.**

**The Code:**

The MVC View which contains the AJAX request:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "PdfButtonCaller";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<h2>PdfButtonCaller</h2>

<button id="pdfClick">Click this</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#pdfClick').click(function () {

            alert('clicked');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'http://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/PdfHandler/PdfButtonCaller',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/pdf',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert('worked');
                    window.open('http://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/PdfHandler/GetPdf');
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error'+ textStatus, errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

WebApi Controller:

```
public class PdfHandlerController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public void PdfButtonCaller()
    {
        var fullPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/readme.pdf");

        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetPdf()
    {
        var fullPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/readme.pdf");

        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
        return response;
    }
}
```

Any help in resolving this XMLHttpRequest request error would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please do a quick search for this problem on StackOverflow - this question has been answered many times.

Comment: Question also comes up daily...google that error ... which you should have done before posting a question here

Comment: Learn about Same Origin Policy and CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your API, you need to set the access-control-allow-origin header to the name of your domain or "*". If you set it to your live domain, then you will also have to set it to localhost if you want to test. It is probably easiest to specify the asterisk, however, that will let any domain use your API.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/7406a8ce-5f9c-4fae-9b0f-e574befb2ee9#SetHTTPheader

```
<set-header name="access-control-allow-origin" exists-action="skip">
    <value>*</value>
</set-header>
```

Or...

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Here is more about the CORS standard:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @ Joshua Dannemann Thanks for supplying me with an actual answer instead of telling me to 'go and search the site'......as if I already hadn't. You put me on the right track with this answer. I implemented CORS through the package manager console then explicitly set access on each web api method to allow the request from my local host MVC site.

Comment: You are welcome. And thank you for returning the favor by accepting my answer!